# c# how to update particular fields

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm brand new to C#, but basically we've got a products table with many foreign keys from other tables, like suppliers, brands, manufacturers etc.

Basically, I've got a form, in which I want the user to be able to update many products in the same screen.

My goal is to update only a couple of fields really, not all the fields from the table.

So, for example, a list of 10 products in one page, each product is one form, which is submitted through ajax. Everything works fine, until the update. Below is what I have:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.products.Attach(product);
            var entry = db.Entry(product);

            entry.Property(e => e.featured).IsModified = true;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Then, I've got an exception "Entity of type "product" in state "Modified" has the following validation errors:" and lists all the required fields like supplier_id, brand_id etc.

I feel that I'm close, but can't figure it out. Been stuck for almost a week now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you are attaching to `db`, and updating `db2`. That will usually not work...

Comment: Error is `Required` bcoz you have mention those field as `Required` in your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've got an exception "Entity of type "product" in state "Modified"
>   has the following validation errors:" and lists all the required
>   fields like supplier_id, brand_id etc.

As this error would suggest when you attempt to `db2.SaveChanges();` some of the fields have not be provided so maybe `null` for example. Try checking the properties of the object to make sure all that are necessary are populated or not null at least.

Also as the comment suggests make sure you save changes to the very thing you make changes on, so if you make changes to `db` then `SaveChanges()` to `db`

Comment: hi sorry.. I'm actually saving it to db, not db2... that was a left over from the tests I was doing. I'll go through your recommendations now and see what happens. Thanks for now.

Comment: Hi again... I've looked into what you said, and it makes sense to load the object(product) and then change the fields I want. I've made it work now with the code below, but not sure if it is a good solution:

        `product originalProduct = db.products.Find(product.id);`
        `originalProduct.featured = product.featured;`
`

Answer (score 0):

you lose information on POST action when you try to save the changes.
This is because you probably doesn't have some properties from your entity in the view form, so the controller doesn't know values for it.
This all happens because MVC is stateless.

Simplest way is to just add hidden fields for all other, non-editable properties.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

These field will be included in POST and hence, model binder will correctly put them into your entity instance.

**But best solutions here it to use view models** - simple POCO classes that will be models for your views. Using entity models directly is not recommended.
When you use view model, you:

- can control what inpormation is displayed on the view,
- can have simple information passed to your controller
- can have additional, view specific information in the model only (not in the entity)

So, when you want to display sth, then you copy this information from entity to view model. On the save method you do it in the oposite way, updating only changed properties on the entity.

Here's some info on that:
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx